# What is a Payload?

Tags: html, browser, payload

Im in webpage and they say: "Download the payload"
They say i can use this to download the payload:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

But what exactly is the payload ?

Comment: Browsing a webpage, html, HTTP Headers, etc. That's the clues i have

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_(computing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_%28computing%29) of a webpage is the HTML (sometimes also incuding images/JS/CSS etc.), i.e. the "interesting" stuff. The HTTP head is the overhead which describes the payload (e.g. size, last date modified), the HTML is the payload.